# ST Bluenrg-ms example codes

Tags: workbench, unresolved-external, bluenrg

there

Has anyone tried any one of the 4 sample codes provided by ST for their Bluenrg-MS evaluation board ?

https://www.st.com/en/wireless-transceivers-mcus-and-modules/bluenrg-ms.html

The sample codes were downloaded from here:

https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-stlkt01.html

I've tried to use stm32cubeide, AC6 and atollic truestudio to open the sample projects, but all of them are giving me the error message such as:

**An internal error occurred during: "Build Project".
java.lang.NullPointerException**

Basically, there are too much unresolved inclusions and variables that it seems to me that the debug/release configuration is not correct. Even 'uint32_t' is unresolved. I've tried the same thing on different PC and getting the same result.

Has any one tried to use these sample codes ? Or is there any other sample codes that are good starting point for this board ?

Thanks.
Eric

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I upgraded to the recent-release STM32CubeIDE 1.0.4 and the STSW-STLKT01_V2.4.0, everything works fine. I guess this is a bug of the old versions.